AMBIGUOUS_REFERENCE error when trying to aggregate a dataframe in azure
Have a dataframe with the following columns
year, month, loc_code, usg_type, id_code, usg
trying to aggregate
in SQL it would have been
select year, month, loc_code, usg_type, count(distinct id_code) as id_count, sum(usg) as traffic
group by all

In Python I've tried the following:
    step4_df = (
        step3_df
            .groupBy("year", "month", "loc_code", "usg_type")
            .agg(
                countDistinct("id_code").alias("id_count"),
                sum("usg").alias("traffic")
            )
    )

But I'm getting a AnalysisException: [AMBIGUOUS_REFERENCE] Reference id_code is ambiguous error. Followed by a list of suggested tables that have nothing to do with I am trying to sum/count.
How do I go about resolving it?
Thank you

The error message you mentioned,

AnalysisException: [AMBIGUOUS_REFERENCE] Reference id_code

Usually When performing a join operation on columns that have the same name in both DataFrames, it is necessary to disambiguate the join condition by specifying the column name as a sequence using Seq("join_column_name"). This helps to avoid any ambiguity and ensures that the join is performed correctly.
is ambiguous, occurs when there is confusion about which column to reference, possibly due to similar column names in joined DataFrames or a mismatch in DataFrame references.
I have tried the below approach:
columns = ["year", "month", "loc_code", "usg_type", "id_code", "usg"]
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("example").getOrCreate()
step3_df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=columns)
step4_df = (
    step3_df
        .groupBy("year", "month", "loc_code", "usg_type")
        .agg(
            countDistinct("id_code").alias("id_count"),
            sum("usg").alias("traffic")
        )
)
step4_df.show()

Results:
+----+-----+--------+--------+--------+-------+
|year|month|loc_code|usg_type|id_count|traffic|
+----+-----+--------+--------+--------+-------+
|2021|    2|    LOC2|   TypeA|       1|    250|
|2021|    2|    LOC2|   TypeB|       1|    450|
|2021|    1|    LOC1|   TypeA|       2|    250|
|2021|    1|    LOC1|   TypeB|       1|    200|
+----+-----+--------+--------+--------+-------+



